# Decoding JPEG image using C

Tags: c, image, jpeg

I have been experimenting with writing a C program to decode a JPEG image, with help from the following website that does the same in Python:

https://yasoob.me/posts/understanding-and-writing-jpeg-decoder-in-python/

I feel like I am almost there, but have a certain number of pixels that are completely the wrong colour. I have attached the original image below that I am trying to decode, which is taken from the above website, together with what I have achieved so far, which is output as a PPM file.

[image]

[image]

Before getting into too much detail with the code itself, I was wondering if anyone can suggest an obvious reason for what I am seeing?

I have used double precision variables for all of the calculations in the inverse DCT, colour conversion stage, etc. I have also checked that the zigzag matrix works ok, and that the inverse DCT code gives correct values for a test input matrix from a textbook.

Comment: You need to include code samples of your attempts, as well as your investigation into what could be wrong. With that being said, please keep in mind StackOverflow is not a debugger.

Comment: Can you show separate Y, Cb, Cr images?

Comment: I managed to get everything working ok. It seems there were two separate problems. Firstly I didn't implement the decoding of the delta encoded DC components correctly, and secondly I needed to change the RGB values from 'unsigned char' to 'int' when writing them to the PPM file. Can anyone explain why this would be a problem, since I had already limited the RGB values to be integers between 0 and 255?